# Android TV Create App with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, android-tv

I'm just doing an app for Android TV. How can I turn a web project (HTML, Javascript and jQuery) into an APK?

Answer (score 0):

Using Cordova, you can make applications for Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phones using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. It is a really helpful tool. You will need to install Android Studio, I'm pretty sure, along with Gradle and NPM on your Windows PC. Phonegap is from Adobe, and it is based off of Cordova. You can install the Phonegap app on your phone, tablet, or even TV and test your application build live over a `localhost` server. Using HTML, you can link to any JavaScript Script, both online and offline. For jQuery, I recommend you download a version for your app, so your application doesn't need an internet connection to run.

Using Plugins, you can use a device's built-in features like GPS and Vibration and Notification. The best part is that it is all translated into JavaScript for easy use!!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
  </li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="$scope.menuitem='app'" ><i class="material-icons dp48">inbox</i>App</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Streaming <i class="material-icons dp48">live_tv</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Music <i class="material-icons dp48">music_note</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Social <i class="material-icons dp48">account_circle</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Game <i class="material-icons dp48">videogame_asset</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Playlist<i class="material-icons dp48">format_list_bulleted</i></a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modalsettings">Settings<i class="material-icons dp48">settings</i></a> </li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>8">inbox</i>App</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Streaming <i class="material-icons dp48">live_tv</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Music <i class="material-icons dp48">music_note</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Social <i class="material-icons dp48">account_circle</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Game <i class="material-icons dp48">videogame_asset</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" ng-click="">Playlist<i class="material-icons dp48">format_list_bulleted</i></a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modalsettings">Settings<i class="material-icons dp48">settings</i></a> </li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#!" class="modal-trigger" href="#modalsetting">Logout<i class="material-icons dp48">exit_to_app</i></a> </li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).